# Google Translate API Error (Unconfigured)

Tags: android, api, translate

I have tried over and over to get this thing to work and I cannot seem to make it happen.

I have hidden apikey...

I have enabled Google Translate API in my account and have made this post as so:

```
public class handleStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                translateTest();
                return null;
            }
        }

    private static byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    void translateTest()
    {
        String apiKey = "HIDDEN...";
        String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key="+apiKey+"&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            //et.append("Try \n");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            //et.append("Pass");
            StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
            //et.append(response.toString());
            if(status.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                //et.append("Error !200\n");    
            }
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int readCount = 0;
            while( (readCount = is.read(buff)) != -1 )
            {
                content.write(buff, 0, readCount);
            }
            String retVal = new String(content.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Output", retVal);
            otp = retVal;
            //et.append("Translate" + retVal);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            //et.append("Exception:\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n");
            Log.d("Output", "Err:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            //throw new ApiException("Server Connect Problem" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
```

I have added Public API access for android and inputted my SHA1;com....
(I have also gone to window>preferences>android>build> and added the debug SHA1)...
However when I run it I get the following response:

```
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472): {
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):  "error": {
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):   "errors": [
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):    {
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):     "domain": "usageLimits",
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):     "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):     "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):    }
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):   ],
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):   "code": 403,
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):   "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472):  }
07-21 22:07:07.264: D/Output(18472): }
```

I know that I have the right API Key because it knows that my app is not allowed.  So it must be something with the SHA1;com... that I am doing wrong, any help would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Google API console (https://console.developers.google.com/) for your project, go to APIs and Auth > Credentials. Under "Key for browser applications," ensure that "Referrers" is set to "any referrer allowed".

If it's not, click Edit Allowed Referrers and clear out any entries.

Comment: This is a key for an Android app

Comment: However, I now realize that I am using an Http request... So Google handles it as a browser.  Thanks, how would one interface this as an android app?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)

Comment: Are there any drawbacks to just interfacing it as a web browser?